# Returning counting result from Firebase Query

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I try to get the amount of rows in my Firebase.
But is says `cannot find counter in scope` on line return counter.

```
extension FourthTabFirstView: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        let ref = database.child("placeID")
        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot!) in
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        let counter = snapshot.childrenCount
        })

        return counter
    }
    ......
    
}
```

Comment: While there is an excellent answer by @sh_khan, what's being done in your question is going to be challenging and should be avoided. You won't want to keep loading data from Firebase over and over while trying to present the tableView; it will be laggy, weird and a bad user experience. Populate the tableView datasource *first*, which is typically an array, and your tableView would pull it's values from that array. `counter` is defined and valid only in the observe closure; hence the error, and `return` call is going to execute way before the data is returned from Firebase and return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Declare this instance variable

```
var counter = 0
```

2-  This should be inside `viewDidLoad`

```
let ref = database.child("placeID")
ref.observe(.value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot: DataSnapshot!) in
   print(snapshot.childrenCount)
   self?.counter = snapshot.childrenCount
   self?.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

3- Change `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return counter
 }
```